# Color of center of contour OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm learning to use OpenCV for recognizing basic figures present in image. I use contour to identify shape and cv2.moments() function to determine center of contour. However when I tried to get #BGR values of center pixel, I got an exception as index out of bound exception. Also the colors of other(non-exceptional figures) contours were not correct. According to me cv2.moment(<_>) returns ***Point*** class object which is not actual co-ordinate. How to cope with this situation? I need to find color of every contour present in image. Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

raw_image = cv2.imread('test5.png')
cv2.imshow('Original Image', raw_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

bilateral_filtered_image = cv2.bilateralFilter(raw_image, 5, 175, 175)
cv2.imshow('Bilateral', bilateral_filtered_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

edge_detected_image = cv2.Canny(bilateral_filtered_image, 75, 200)
cv2.imshow('Edge', edge_detected_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edge_detected_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contour_list = []
myMap = {}

for contour in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.02*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
    #area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if ((len(approx) >= 3)):
        contour_list.append(contour)
        M = cv2.moments(contour)
        xx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        yy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        print(raw_image[xx][yy])
        #shape recognization code ahead
```

And the image is:
[image]
And the exception:

```
  File "colourTmp.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(raw_image[xx][yy])
IndexError: index 788 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 598
```

When I print shape of *raw_img* it came to (598, 898, 3).
How should I proceed?

Comment: `raw_image[xx][yy]` -- wrong order of indices, first should be row, second the column. Usually the vertical axis is considered to be `y`, and the horizontal `x`.

Comment: But when I see the docs, Cx=m10/m00. See here [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: I'm not debating that part. I'm simply saying that you're indexing the array incorrectly, the last statement ought to be `raw_image[yy][xx]`.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!

Comment: While this is unrelated, keep in mind that since you're getting the whole contour hierarchy (`cv2.RETR_TREE`) from the `edge_detected_image`, you will get two contours for each shape -- an external one, that corresponds to the while outline, and an internal one, that corresponds to the black "filling". That might not be desireable.